# pd.read_html importing a long string rather than a table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import

I used pd.read_html to try and import a table, but I'm getting a long string instead when I run it. Is there a simple way to change the format of the result to get 1 word per row rather than a long string, or should i be using a function other than pd.read_html? Thank you!

here is my code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
url ='http://www.linfo.org/acronym_list.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(url, header =0)
df = pd.concat(dfs)
df
```

i also used this and got the same result:

```
import pandas as pd
url ='http://www.linfo.org/acronym_list.html'
data = pd.read_html(url, header=0)
data[0]
```

Out[1]:

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ A AMD Advanced Micro Devices API application programming interface ARP address resolution protocol ARPANET Advanced Research Projects Agency Network AS autonomous system ASCII American Standard Code for Information Interchange AT&T American Telephone and Telegraph Company ATA advanced technology attachment ATM asynchronous transfer mode B B byte BELUG Bellevue Linux Users Group BGP border gateway protocol...

Comment: Can you show a sample of what `'http://www.linfo.org/acronym_list.html'` looks like?

Comment: @Brandon LOL.  just navigate there.

Comment: Lol, good point.

Comment: Did you inspect the source?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how the table was created in this site.

According to  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp, an HTML table is defined with the < table > tag. Each table row is defined with the < tr > tag. A table header is defined with the < th > tag. By default, table headings are bold and centered. A table data/cell is defined with the < td > tag.

If you press CTRL+SHIFT+I, you can inspect the html elements of your site and you will see that this site does not follow this standard. That is why you are not getting the correct dataframe using pandas.read_html.

Comment: thank you for that, i had looked through the page source but didn't know that info so I appreciate it. I'll assume it was the dataframe command itself that was screwing the results, so is there some simple code to extract a result of something resembling a table from all the <p> tags?